# Is there any way to share webpack configs via npm?

Tags: webpack

Here the problem; I want to put my webpack configs & the related deps in an shared npm package;

So they could be versioned, shared across multiple projects, plugin & external components.

Haven't found any existing solution for webpack :(

Is there any way of doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[layer-pack](https://github.com/n8tz/layer-pack) can do that.

It allow making "inheritable" projects, including theirs webpack configs & come with a small CLI tool to call webpack with the right config

Also it come with some nice features like glob resolving.

There is samples [here](https://github.com/n8tz/layer-pack-samples) & doc [here](https://github.com/n8tz/layer-pack/blob/master/DOC.MD)

Hope it help :)